# Click() method is not working on HyperLink object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call `click()` method dynamically on an object of a hyper link through java script code.Getting error that `click()` is not a method.

Can someone please let me know how can I do this.I tried to wrap this object around Mootools and JQuery object.Still did not get through.

Here is some code demonstration

```
<a href="abc.jsp" id="myLink1">Click here</a>
<a href="abcd.jsp" id="myLink2">Click here</a>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(){
        $('myLink1').click(function() {
       //doing some reporting stuff
        });

       $('myLink2').click(function() {
       //doing some reporting stuff
       });
  }

//I need some way ,click event to be fired on links depending on some conditions.

function clickDynamically()
{
  if(clickFirstLink)
         document.getElementById('myLink1').click(); // does not work , it says click is not a method
  else
    document.getElementById('myLink2').click();
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you post some code demonstrating this? We can't help you without understanding what is going on.

Comment: <a href="abc.jsp" id="myLink1">Click here</a>
<a href="abcd.jsp" id="myLink2">Click here</a>
jQuery(document).ready(){
        $('myLink1').click(function() {
       //doing some reporting stuff
    });
  $('myLink2').click(function() {
       //doing some reporting stuff
    });
  }
//I need some way to click event to be fired on links depending on some conditions.
function clickDynamically()
{
  if(clickFirstLink)
         document.getElementById('myLink1').click(); // does not work , it says click is not a method
  else
 document.getElementById('myLink2').click();
}

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you would do this:

```
$("#mylink").click();
```

If you're not using jQuery, you would do this:

```
document.getElementById('mylink').click();
```

Note, you'll need to make sure you set up the event handler first. In jQuery, you'll do it like this:

```
$("#mylink").click(function() { alert("works"); });
```

**EDIT**

In response to your comment, here is a working example that you can build off of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        $(function() {

            // Example #1
            // Set up different click handlers on each link
            // Be sure to return false so the browser DOESN'T
            // follow the links.

            $("#link-1").click(function() {

                alert("Link #1");

                return false;

            });

            $("#link-2").click(function() {

                alert("Link #2");

                return false;

            });

            //////// OR /////////

            // Example #2
            // Set up 1 click handler and use logic to determine
            // which link was clicked.
            // Be sure to return false so the browser DOESN'T
            // follow the links.

            $("#link-1, #link-2").click(function() {

                var $LinkThatWasClicked = $(this);

                if ($LinkThatWasClicked.attr("id") == "link-1") {

                    // Do something if it's link 1
                    alert("We figured out it is link #1");

                } else {

                    // Do something if it's link 2
                    alert("We figured out it is link #2");

                }

                return false;

            });

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <a href="#" id="link-1">Click Link #1</a>
    <a href="#" id="link-2">Click Link #2</a>

</body>
</html>
```

I think the issue with the jQuery code you posted was simply that you **forgot the hash symbol** before `myLink`. The has tells jQuery to look for an element with an `ID` of `myLink`. Without the hash, jQuery was looking for an element with a `tagName` of `myLink`, which is invalid.

Hope the example helps.

Comment: The `click()` method on DOM elements works only in Opera and IE.

Comment: @Sime That's right. It's been so long since I've used plain ole' javascript for event invoking that I completely forgot. Oh well, I think the OP said he was using jQuery anyway.

Comment: <a href="abc.jsp" id="myLink1">Click here</a>
<a href="abcd.jsp" id="myLink2">Click here</a>
jQuery(document).ready(){
        $('myLink1').click(function() {
       //doing some reporting stuff
    });
  $('myLink2').click(function() {
       //doing some reporting stuff
    });
  }
//I need some way to click event to be fired on links depending on some conditions.
function clickDynamically()
{
  if(clickFirstLink)
         document.getElementById('myLink1').click(); // does not work , it says click is not a method
  else
 document.getElementById('myLink2').click();
}

Comment: @Gopal, I've added another example for you. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
window.location = document.getElementById("myLink").href;
```

Comment: thanks !! Not sure how will help me .i do not see any click method called on it

Answer (score 0):

```
  jQuery(document).ready(){
        $('yourVar').click(function() {
       //your code
    });
  }
```

it will work in any case :)

Comment: I have link that allready has call back function attached to it thru jquery.
Now I am trying to show a model pop up ( ovlerlay ) on click of my link.My overlay has two button yes and no.
When control comes to function that is called onclick in yes button , I am able to get the object of link that was clicked as i stored it.

Now i am calling click() on it so that all callback(previously attached) can be triggered and i can proceed to next page.

Comment: add some code as it is not clear from your post what actually you want.

Comment: <a href="abc.jsp" id="myLink1">Click here</a>
<a href="abcd.jsp" id="myLink2">Click here</a>
jQuery(document).ready(){
        $('myLink1').click(function() {//doing some reporting stuff
    });
  }
jQuery(document).ready(){
        $('myLink2').click(function() {
       //doing some reporting stuff
    });
  }
//I need some way to click event to be fired on links depending on some conditions.
function clickDynamically()
{
  if(clickFirstLink)
 document.getElementById('myLink1').click(); // does not work , it says click is not a method
  else
 document.getElementById('myLink2').click();
}